# array and pointer chain

Tags: c, pointers, arr

As written in c books,an array name is a pointer to first element so here in names array,names points to first element which is also a pointer to string literal,then *names will print the first element,but in next line of code p points to a,and q points to q like names arr,but as u print *q u dont get a value which is 3,why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    char *names[]={"jack","philip"};
    printf("%s\n",*names);
    int a=3;
    int *p=&a;
    int *q=&p;
    printf("%i\n",*q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry,in line 3 of question second q is p not q,miss typed

Comment: it should be int ** q, &p is the address of an int pointer, to get your last print to print 3, do **q

Comment: If you do like @RyanFitzpatrick sugested, `q` is equivalent to `&p`, `*q` is equivalent to `&a`. `**q` is equivalent to `a` which stores `3`.

Comment: **q not working,i've tried

Comment: @VahidEf q must be of type int** see my answer for a working version of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is an `int`, so `p` is a pointer to an `int` (`int *`), thus `q` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int` (`int **`). To print an `int`, you feed that `int` to `printf`:

```
printf("This is an int: %i\n", 42);
```

So for `%i` the function `printf` expects an argument of type `int`, but you pass `*q` to it, which is of type `int *`. You pass a pointer to `printf`, which does not expect a pointer for numbers, only for strings.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in `printf()`. The `%s` expects a pointer to a null terminated string, while `%i` expects to be handed the number itself, not a pointer to the number, which is what you have.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the working code should look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *names[]={"jack","philip"};
    printf("%s\n",*names);
    int a=3;
    int *p=&a;
    int **q=&p;
    printf("%i\n",**q);
    return 0;
}
```

%s expects a char* which as you correctly stated is what *names is, since names is of type char**. However %i expects an int. Since p points to a, p is an int pointer, since q points to p q is a pointer to an int pointer. *q is just whatever p is pointing at (the address of a) so it won't print what you want. also assigning type int* to the address of an int* (which is what youre doing when you do int* q = &p) will have unexpected results

```
printf("%i", *q);
```

would be like doing

```
printf("%c", *names);
```

which obviously will give strange output